# Maximum call stack size exceeded when trying to attach load to img with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have a simple image i select with (i've also try `on()` and `one()`):

```
$container.find('.thumbnail img').load(function(){
  $container.trigger('resize');
});
```

For some reason tho I get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I'm loading these images from an S3 instance if that matters. I know it does redirects a few times, but I dont think that'd matter.

Has anyone run into this or something similar. I don't feel like this should ever be an infinite loop. This also happens intermittently which is more confusing.

The resize stuff:

```
publicMethod.resize = function (options) {
    if (open) {
        options = options || {};

        if (options.width) {
            settings.w = setSize(options.width, 'x') - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth;
        }
        if (options.innerWidth) {
            settings.w = setSize(options.innerWidth, 'x');
        }
        $loaded.css({width: settings.w});

        if (options.height) {
            settings.h = setSize(options.height, 'y') - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight;
        }
        if (options.innerHeight) {
            settings.h = setSize(options.innerHeight, 'y');
        }
        if (!options.innerHeight && !options.height && $loaded.find('iframe').length == 0) {
            var $child = $loaded.wrapInner("<div style='overflow:auto'></div>").children(); // temporary wrapper to get an accurate estimate of just how high the total content should be.
            settings.h = $child.height();
            $child.replaceWith($child.children()); // ditch the temporary wrapper div used in height calculation
        }
        if("scrollTop" in options) {
            settings.scrollTop = options.scrollTop;
        }
        $loaded.css({height: settings.h});

        publicMethod.position(settings.transition === "none" ? 0 : settings.speed);
    }
};
```

Comment: Show your code, what are you doing in response to the resize event?

Comment: I'm working in a massive code base, so i can't copy and paste it all. I'll try to grab whatever you're looking for tho. I've added the resize code which is from colorbox.js

Comment: How many images are we talking about?

Comment: One. And to be 100% sure (even tho im checking the `.length` on the jQuery selection) i've also tried selecting `img:first`

Comment: have you tried chrome's break on DOM event debugging flags?  There's also console.trace to give you the stack trace at a given point or just put "debugger" on its own line to step through inside your resize function to see what's calling it every time. (apologies if you are already aware of this, it's just where I'd start if you don't have a minimal example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a couple days of debugging this I *finally* tracked down the issue. The problem is a shim a developer on the Rails side a few months prior by Paul Irish that overrode an internal jQuery `special.add` method which completely broke any `img.load()` stuff. The snippet looks like this (and it's deployed all over the web actually, but doesn't cause an issue until jQuery 1.6-1.7+

```
/*
 * Special event for image load events
 * Needed because some browsers does not trigger the event on cached images.

 * MIT License
 * Paul Irish     | @paul_irish | www.paulirish.com
 * Andree Hansson | @peolanha   | www.andreehansson.se
 * 2010.
 *
 * Usage:
 * $(images).bind('load', function (e) {
 *   // Do stuff on load
 * });
 * 
 * Note that you can bind the 'error' event on data uri images, this will trigger when
 * data uri images isn't supported.
 * 
 * Tested in:
 * FF 3+
 * IE 6-8
 * Chromium 5-6
 * Opera 9-10
 */
(function ($) {
    $.event.special.load = {
        add: function (hollaback) {
            if ( this.nodeType === 1 && this.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img' && this.src !== '' ) {
                // Image is already complete, fire the hollaback (fixes browser issues were cached
                // images isn't triggering the load event)
                if ( this.complete || this.readyState === 4 ) {
                    hollaback.handler.apply(this);
                }

                // Check if data URI images is supported, fire 'error' event if not
                else if ( this.readyState === 'uninitialized' && this.src.indexOf('data:') === 0 ) {
                    $(this).trigger('error');
                }

                else {
                    $(this).bind('load', hollaback.handler);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

So if you're working on a large code base that uses jQuery and you're getting call stack exceeded errors while trying to do an image load, this shim was probably added at some point.

Comment: Any updates?  I have the same dilemma but need to keep the image load shim to detect images stored in the cache.

Comment: @mrbinky3000 this was fixed in jQuery. You only need this if you're on a super old version of jQuery (like, <1.5). If you _are_ then you need this and it wont cause any problems